# Prolog: X is the grandfather of Y

Tags: prolog

Assume that the following facts are already entered into the Prolog database:

```
father(X, Y)     // X is the father of Y
mother(X, Y)     // X is the mother of Y
male(X)          // X is a male
female(X)        // X is a female
parent(X, Y)     // X is a parent of Y
diff(X, Y)       // X and Y are different
```

(1) Now add a Prolog rule for grandpa_of(X, Y) where "X is the grandfather of Y"

(2) Add another rule for sibling(X, Y) where "X is the sibling of Y"

My thoughts:

Question 1:

I am confused on how I can find the parents of the parents, all I have so far is

grandpa_of(X,Y) :- male(X), ...

Question 2:

sibling(X, Y) :- parent(P, X), parent(P, Y), diff(X, Y)

Comment: If X is the grandfather of Y, what does that say about Y's father/mother?

Comment: @Paul: Class is over, this is from a past final.  So I do need to learn it, but it is not for marks.

Comment: @Anon: That their male parent is a grandfather to Y?

Comment: Right. So if X is the grandfather of Y, then there has to be someone who is a parent of Y, and has X as their father. How would we go about writing that down?

Comment: grandpa_of(X, Y) :- father(X, P), father(P, Y).  This would first find the children of X, and then use those children in the next line, to see if one is the father of Y.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Jason means `grandpa_of(X,Y) :- father(X,P), parent(P,Y).`

Comment: There is a typo above. Instead of `:=` there should be `:-`.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a long time... The first one is something like this:

```
grandpa_of(X, Y) :- father(X, P), father(P, Y).
```

Been too long... :-P

Answer (score 0):

Hamad is the parent of Bilal, Laiba, and Marium.
Ali and Mona are Hamad's parents.
Musarat is also the parent of Bilal, Laiba, and Marium.
Kamran and Javeria are her parents.
Kamran and Javeria are also the parents of Salma, and Umar.
Parents are ancestors as are ancestors of parents.
Siblings share a parent.

1. mother
2. brother
3. grandfather
4. uncle
5. aunt

```
male(hamad).
male(bilal).
male(ali).
male(kamran).
male(umar).

female(laiba).
female(marium).
female(mona).
female(musarat).
female(javeria).
female(salma).

parents(ali, hamad).
parents(mona, hamad).

parents(kamran, musarat).
parents(javeria, musarat).

parents(kamran, salma).
parents(kamran, umar).

parents(javeria, salma).
parents(javeria, umar).

parents(hamad, bilal).
parents(hamad, laiba).
parents(hamad, marium).

parents(musarat, bilal).
parents(musarat, laiba).
parents(musarat, marium).



mother(X, Y) :-
    parents(X, Y),
    female(X),
    write(X),
    write(' is a mother of '),
    write(Y),
    nl.

brother(X, Y) :-
    male(X),
    x \= y,
    parents(Z, X),
    parents(Z, Y),
    write(X),
    write(' is a brother of '),
    write(Y),
    nl.

sister(X, Y) :-
    female(X),
    x \= y,
    parents(Z, X),
    parents(Z, Y),
    write(X),
    write(' is a sister of '),
    write(Y),
    nl.

grandfather(X, Y) :-
    parents(X, P),
    parents(P, Y),
    male(X),
    write(X),
    write(' is grandfather of '),
    write(Y),
    nl.

uncle(X, Z) :-
    brother(X, P),
    parents(P, Z),
    male(X),
    write(X),
    write(' is an uncle of '),
    write(Z),
    nl.

aunt(X, Z) :-
    sister(X, P),
    parents(P, Z),
    female(X),
    write(X),
    write(' is an aunt of '),
    write(Z),
    nl.
```

Answer (score -1):

Sample program of X is a Grandfather of Y

```
%knowledgebase or database

female(amrita).
 
female(aroti).

female(manusi).

female(parboti).

male(susanta).

male(prasanta).

male(haran).

male(ratan).

male(srijit).

%clause 

parent(manusi,susanta).

parent(ratan,amrita).

parent(aroti,amrita).

parent(haran,prasanta).

parent(haran,susanta).

parent(manusi,prasanta).

parent(susanta,srijit).

%rules

mother(X,Y):-parent(X,Y),female(X).

father(X,Y):-parent(X,Y),male(X).

sister(X,Y):-female(X),x\==y,parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y).

brother(X,Y):-male(X),x\==y,parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y).

grandparent(X,Y):-parent(X,Y),parent(Y,Z).

grandmother(X,Y):-mother(X,Y),parent(Y,Z).

grandfather(X,Y):-father(X,Y),parent(Y,Z).
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).